# Buttons not showing up

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

I have this code in activity_maps.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></fragment>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="492dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRestaurant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Restaurants"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHospital"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Hospitals"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSchool"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Schools"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

The problem that I am facing is that whenever I open the app it is showing none of the buttons, only the map and the current location. Please Help, Thank You.

Comment: Why did you put the buttons in FrameLayout?

Comment: Your layout is messed up . Here is a good place to start https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html.

Answer (score 1):

Your map fragment height is given as "match_parent", that's why it takes all the screen on your layout. keep it as wrap_content and use relative layout to make sure that the buttons are present on the screen at the bottom. here **"alignParentTop"** in the map fragment makes sure the map is on top of the screen and **layout_above** makes sure your map does not take all the screen, **"alignParentBottom"** in the button layout makes sure the buttons are on the bottom. try not to assign any static height to your layout. it will hamper the responsiveness of your app.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_buttons"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_contant"></fragment>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_buttons"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRestaurant"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nearby Restaurants"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnHospital"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nearby Hospitals"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSchool"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nearby Schools"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there is an error saying Error:error: attribute 'android:alignParentBottom' not found, Error:error: attribute 'android:alignParentTop' not found, Error:attribute 'android:alignParentTop' not found, Error:attribute 'android:alignParentBottom' not found

Comment: sorry, wrong attribute name by me, it will be "android:layout_alignParentTop" and "android:layout_alignParentBottom"

Comment: the buttons are  showing up and the app is just blank with buttons only, if I press the buttons it just shows the toast message

Answer (score 0):

please put fragment inside the framelayout

like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></fragment>

<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRestaurant"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Restaurants"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHospital"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Hospitals"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSchool"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nearby Schools"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

hope this will help you ,Thanks :)

Comment: Dude, just give me the design how you want the layout,

Comment: Hey create a layout with framelayout and copy the fragment and  linearlayout. Please add orientation in linearlayout